# Replication doesn't start after reinitializing in MS SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, replication, transactional-replication

After subscription had been marked for reinitialize, a new snapshot was generated.
Log reader and queue reader agents are running.

But when we try to turn on the synchronizing, we're getting the following error:
*The concurrent snapshot for publication 'DBName' is not available because it has not been fully generated or the Log Reader Agent is not running to activate it. If generation of the concurrent snapshot was interrupted, the Snapshot Agent for the publication.*

Once we got it synchronizing well(no idea how it was, it just started working without our participation), but because of foreign keys(and unsynchronised part of data) we had to reinit it all from start.

Here is our publication properties:
[image: publication properties]

How to get it synchronising well?

Comment: We found a message in LogFileViewer:
Replication-Replication Transaction-Log Reader Subsystem: agent Computer-Name-DBName-1 scheduled for retry. The process could not execute 'sp_replcmds' on 'Computer-Name'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've figured out the problem and [this is  a solution](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/811030)

Comment: This link is dead, this is why you explain your answer in detail. This is worthless now.